# I can't join the name column. can you tell me what's the error in my query?

Tags: postgresql

I can't join the name column. can you tell me what's the error in my query? there's no error message but all values of name column is null. can some one help me? please see snip below and my query below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t98Td.png) [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h6BsO.png)

Comment: Please do **not** post code as images. See here for more details why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551

Comment: Maybe you need to quote the name, like companies."name"

Comment: both tables have different `market` values, so the left join returns `null` for the the `right` table. It could be a matter of spaces or hidden characters like a line return.